# Perl $ENV equivalent in PHP to get variable

Tags: php, perl

I have a perl file that gets the filename of a `POST` attachment.

```
my $file_name = $ENV{'HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION'};
$file_name =~ s/^attachment; filename=\"(.*)\"$/$1/;
```

What is the equivalent in PHP? Is this just `filename` as a POST variable?

Sorry for if this is a noob question. My perl is bad and my PHP noob level. :)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request headers are populated into the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/$_SERVER) variable.

```
$content_disposition = $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION'];
if (!$content_disposition) {
    throw new Exception('Content-Disposition header missing');
}
if (preg_match(
    '/^attachment; filename="(?P<file_name>.*)"$/',
    $content_disposition,
    $matches
)) {
    // do something with $matches['file_name']
} else {
    throw new Exception(
        'filename match in Content-Disposition header failed, error: ' .
        preg_last_error()
    );
}
```

That regex is a quite poor way to parse a header (in any programming language).

You should really delegate the task to more robust code and use [a higher-level library to handle uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files), method name is [`getClientOriginalName`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php#L107).

Comment: That worked first time. I'll improve on parsing the header. Thanks for your help. :)